# AWS multiple instance connect through ssh from command line (without remembering keypairname and user)

Tags: python, bash, shell, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I have four AWS accounts with more than 50 instances. Daily I have to connect most of them. So every time when I want to connect instances through ssh, have to login AWS accounts first and then have to find the keypair name and IP. Because it's very difficult to remember all IP's and keypair. So I want tools or scripts to make it easily done without remembering the keypair name and user.

Notes: I have downloaded keypair
connect via ssh from command line: ssh -i kepairname user@IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `~/.ssg/config` options.
Someting like that:

```
Host server1
Hostname 1.2.3.4
User user1
IdentityFile kepairname1


Host server2
Hostname 1.2.3.5
User user2
IdentityFile kepairname2
```

After that you will be able to connect to your hosts just with

```
ssh server1
ssh server2
```

If you use any other options, any of them can be added to that config. As always, full info in `man ssh_config`.

And if you want to have interactive selection, you can use simple bash script. In that example I created directory `~/.ssh/config.d/` and created configs:

```
$ ls -1 ~/.ssh/config.d/
AWS
DigitalOcean
```

Then that simple script can be used to interactively connect to your servers:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Defining constant
CONFIG_DIR="$HOME/.ssh/config.d/"

# Add providers to array
PROVIDERS=($(ls -1 "$CONFIG_DIR"))

# select uses PS3 as a prompt
PS3='Select provider: '
select prov in ${PROVIDERS[@]}; do
  if [[ -n $prov ]]; then
    provider=$prov
    echo "You have selected $provider"
    break
  else
    echo 'Wrong selection.'
  fi
done

# Defining config file and parsing instances from it
CONF_FILE="${CONFIG_DIR}${provider}"
INSTANCES=($(awk '/Host / {print $2}' "$CONF_FILE"))

PS3='Select instance: '
select inst in ${INSTANCES[@]}; do
  if [[ -n $inst ]]; then
    instance=$inst
    echo "You have selected $instance"
    ssh -F "$CONF_FILE" $instance
    break
  else
    echo 'Wrong selection.'
  fi
done
```

And it works like that:

```
$ bash test.sh
1) AWS
2) DigitalOcean
Select provider: 34
Wrong selection.
Select provider: 2
You have selected DigitalOcean
1) server1
2) server2
Select instance: 2
You have selected server2
ssh: connect to host 1.2.3.5 port 22: No route to host
```

Comment: Suppose I want to create sheel scripts and output look like: 

--------
SSH LOGIN
--------
1. AWS 
2. DigitalOcean
3. Others
-----

Comment: if they press 1 then go to AWS account...1.1 account1 1.2 account2 >>>when they go account1 >>> then found 1.1.1 instance1 1.1.2 instance2 >>> so find out the host name and login easily...

Comment: @IftikharHossain Added script for interactive selection.